# Terraform - output variables as quoted values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure

I'm using Terraform to build our AWS infrastructure projects. I need to be able to output multiple variables to a file and then to load that file back into another Terraform script.

Right now, I'm able to output the variables but they come out with the values not quoted:

```
variable = value
```

However, when loading a variable file into Terraform, it expects all values to be quoted, like this:

```
variable = "value"
```

So I can't understand why the hell Terraform doesn't just export the variables that way in the first place.

Is there any way to have it do this without requiring additional work on my part?

EDIT: I'm using Terraform v0.11.13 and cannot upgrade due to security restrictions

Comment: Why would you do this rather than use remote state or better yet a proper data source? If that can't work for you have you tried writing to a file using the local_file resource instead of using outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Output in JSON and use JQ to transform into what you like to have.

```
terraform output -json
```

#### main.tf

```
output "hogehoge" {
  value = "hogehoge"
}
```

#### Execution

```
$ terraform apply
Outputs:
hogehoge = hogehoge

$ terraform output -json
{
  "hogehoge": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "hogehoge"
  }
}
```

However, as @ydaetskcoR commented, why not use `data.terraform_remote_state`?